# Sobolev chain rule on non-compact manifolds

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, riemannian-geometry, sobolev-spaces

Let $(M,g)$ be a non-compact Riemannian manifold (not of bounded geometry).

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be $C^1$ with $f'$ bounded and $f(0)=0$. Is the Sobolev chain rule valid for functions $u \in H^1(M)$:
$$\nabla_g f(u) = f'(u)\nabla_g u \quad\in L^2(M)?$$

Seems to me true by density of smooth functions but I wonder if I have missed anything.

Answer (score 2):

Since $f'$ is bounded, it is clear that $\nabla_gf(u)$ is in $L^2$ if $\nabla_gu$ is.
It just remains to check that your formula indeed gives the weak gradient of $f(u)$.
Weak derivatives on manifolds are often define on the coordinate charts (it suffices to consider test functions supported in a single chart), and it does not matter for such calculations whether $M$ is compact or not.
It sounds like you already know the result is true on compact manifolds, and the noncompact case is not different.